# How to use csrf token when doing POST request in Postman

Tags: postman, csrf, csrf-token

I am trying to do a POST request in Postman, and I know I have to use CSRF Token to successfully receive data back. I used inspect element to find the csrf token on my browser, but don't know how to send it in Postman. How can I go about doing this?

[This is the error message I am receiving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCp3D.png)

edit: This is what the api documentation says about the headers:

```
Parameters (http headers):
    
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<filename> -- a name of the file (see rfc6266).
    
Authorization: license <user license> -- a user license, optional (if there is no license it is necessary to use csrf tokens)
```

Comment: Is that laravel?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just wanted to try out an api service this website offers and am fairly new to postman and using csrf tokens.

Comment: Well technically it shouldn't ask if its an api, because apis are now powered with CORS. If this is some legacy service there might be an endpoint to get one

Comment: It is a paid service, and it normally uses a license of a user as a header, but there is a free version which requires csrf tokens if there is no license.

Comment: Maybe possibly your headers are wrong, or you're requesting to a wrong endpoint?

Comment: I've checked my headers, I don't think they are wrong. The error message I am receiving pertains to csrf token.